# Geometric interpretation for the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory

Discussing with some friends, the following question arose:

If $\nu$ is a signed measure, $\mu$ is a positive measure, and they're both $\sigma$-finite, then we may write $\nu = \lambda+\rho$, where $\lambda \perp \mu$ and $\rho = f\,{\rm d}\mu \ll \mu$.

The set ${\rm Meas}(X,{\cal M})$ of all signed measures in a fixed measurable space $(X,{\cal M})$ is not a vector space, but it behaves almost like one. And identifying $\mu$ with ${\rm d}\mu$ given by ${\rm d}\mu(E) = \int_E {\rm d}\mu$, we can think of "tangent spaces" $T_\mu({\rm Meas}(X,{\cal M}))$. And even if $L^1_{\rm ext}(\mu)$ denotes the set of all $\mu$-extended integrable functions, this is not a ring, but nevertheless we'd like to say that each of these "tangent spaces" behaves like a $L^1_{\rm ext}(\mu)$-module. And the Lebesgue decomposition ends up being a decomposition of each "tangent space" as the ("$\mu$-a.e.") orthogonal direct sum of the sets of singular signed measures w.r.t. $\mu$ and the absolutely continuous measures w.r.t. $\mu$, in the sense that we can draw a $\mu$-plane and see ${\rm d}\nu = {\rm d}\lambda + f\,{\rm d}\mu$ as an equality of "tangent vectors".

We understand that there should be *some* reason for the use of the symbol $\perp$ in this context (and $\ll$ is some sort of parallelism relation). So:

> **Question:** what is the correct algebraic or geometric structure on ${\rm Meas}(X,{\cal M})$ which allows us to formalize this interpretation?

Comment: The structure on the space of finite signed measures which makes the Radon-Nikodym theorem tick is that of a Riesz space - the theorem is more or less a trivial consequence of the Freudenthal spectral theorem in that setting.  So you might start by trying to generalize the notion of a Riesz space to an object which includes the space of signed measures; the right generalization ought to have its own Freudenthal spectral theorem.

Comment: It's also worth noting that von Neumann's proof of the Radon-Nikodym theorem provides some motivation for the symbols $\perp$ and $\ll$: the Radon-Nikodym decomposition is more or less the orthogonal decomposition of $\mu$ relative to the subspace $L^2(\nu)$ of $L^2(\mu + \nu)$, viewing $\mu$ as an element of $L^2(\mu + \nu)$ via the Riesz representation theorem.  That is the geometric interpretation of the theorem that I bear in mind.